# Why is the CSS style not working on my div in react js?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, jsx

I'm pretty new to react js and I'm having trouble with a div in a component. For some reason, the CSS just isn't working for it. Please can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
export const Main = () => {
    return (
        <div className = "main">

            <h1>SO CHEESY</h1>

        </div>

    )
}
```

This is the component named Main.js

```
.main {
  background-color: #161616;
}
```

This is the style in the index.css file. This isn't exactly what I'm trying to do but this is just an example. Nothing seems to work.

I've tried everything I know. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Did you import the css file into the Main.js component ?

Comment: No, I didn't. I usually don't need to when I'm styling in the index.css file. It's been imported in the index.js file already and it usually works just fine for me.

Comment: You need to import the css file and it will work as i already told :-)

Comment: I did that. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the Main.js:

```
import './index.css';
```